# PHP Rest client for JHipster API with session auth

Tags: php, rest, spring-boot, jhipster

I have developed a system using Jhipster and its technologies. I'm trying now to create a REST client in PHP to connect to the API generated by Jhipster, but I could not authenticate. I've tried with php_curl, guzzle and I always get 401.

Please if anyone has any client rest for the Jhipster API and knows how to achieve authentication I would appreciate your help. I am using session for authentication in Jhipster / spring

Comment: Have you tried to generate a PHP client using swagger-codegen from `http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs`? https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#getting-started  Also session auth requires storing jssessionid cookie, does your PHP code handle this? Your post lack some details about when you get a 401.

Comment: Thanks, I generate the client code using codegen ... is excellent tool. The PHP code generate showme in the doc ```php
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

$api_instance = new Swagger\Client\Api\AccountresourceApi();
$key = "key_example"; // string | key
try {
    $result = $api_instance->activateAccountUsingGET($key);
    print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception when calling AccountresourceApi->activateAccountUsingGET: ', $e->getMessage(), 
}

?>
``` But I'm need know how i can access to "token", any idea, function to call or something ?

Answer (score 1):

Session authentication might not be the easiest authentication mechanism for such a use-case, maybe JWT would be better for you.

What you need to do is go through the authentication form (do a "POST" and send the login/password), and that will give you a token (a "jsessionid", this is the standard for Java application). You can check this if you use Chrome Dev Tools.

Then, you need to use this "jsessionid" for your next requests.

If you generate your application with the "Gatling" option (in the available tests frameworks), this will generate the correct configuration for doing the authentication and doing the requests: Gatling is coded in Scala, but that will give a good example, which you can copy.

Comment: Thanks @julien, I need know at what page do a POST call, reading the angular webapp code I see the api/authentication service, but not is readable from swagger api. It is the service for authentication that i need?